# Regular expression to remove space in the beginning of each line?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove space in the beggining of each line.

I have data in each line with a set of spaces in the beginning  so data appears in the middle, I want to remove spaces in the beginning of each line.

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g,"")
```

How can I add the `^\s` condition into that `replace()`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To remove all leading spaces:

```
str = str.replace(/^ +/gm, '');
```

The regex is quite simple - one or more spaces at the start. The more interesting bits are the flags - `/g` (global) to replace all matches and not just the first, and `/m` (multiline) so that the caret matches the beginning of each line, and not just the beginning of the string.

Working example: **http://jsbin.com/oyeci4**

Comment: @kiran - `.replace(/[.?]/g, ' ')` can do that, but that's a whole other question... What are you trying to do? First you're removing spaces, then `<>` tags, now other characters... Oh, and unless your string is huge, there isn't a great benefit in trying to do it all in one line.

Comment: replace(/[.?]/g, ' '), this one is not giving the reqired result

Answer (score 11):

```
var text = "          this is a string         \n"+
           "    \t    with a much of new lines     \n";
text.replace(/^\s*/gm, '');
```

this supports multiple spaces of different types including tabs.

Comment: @Grabiel thanks, it worked .. can you explain what is that 'm' for i know 'g' is for global

Comment: @kiran `m` indicates multi-line mode.

Comment: @kiran if it worked, maybe you can mark it as the answer. And as alex indicated `m` allows the parser to treat each line with the whole regex.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to remove one space, then this regex is all you need:

```
^\s
```

So in JavaScript:

```
yourString.replace(/(?<=\n) /gm,"");
```

Comment: i tried this, but i need to remove from each line seperated by \n

Comment: @kiran so you want to replace spaces with newlines?

Comment: This should only replace a space after a newline character, without replacing the \n.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support look-behind. Sad but true.