# Remove white space from beginning and end of LINES

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a website where you can browse software licenses for your project. I am currently having trouble removing spaces at the beginning of the lines when you copy a license.

screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cv0h.png)

i have been trying various regular expressions, but none of them seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove whitespace  from the beginning of a line, use

```
.replace(/^[^\S\r\n]+/gm, "")
```

Pattern details:

- `^` - start of a line (since multiline modifier /m is used)
- `[^\S\r\n]` - matches any character other than a nonwhitespace, carriage return and line feed characters. `+` makes it match one or more occurrences.

Comment: You're a saint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **trim** for such things. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: This is only for the beginning and end of the STRING i want it for all of the LINES.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var text = "          this is a string         \n"+
       "    \t    with a much of new lines     \n";
text.replace(/^\s*/gm, '');
```

[Regular expression to remove space in the beginning of each line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799801/regular-expression-to-remove-space-in-the-beginning-of-each-line/5799836#5799836)

Comment: sort of works but it removes all of the spaces, even the ones between the paragraphs. screenshot ---> https://gyazo.com/4bccdba29ae8d1df15e26be615df9906